# How do I move to another UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am currently executing a method in `CurrentViewController` and I want to move to my `FirstViewController` (this the actual name of the ViewController I want to move to) when I reach the end of the method that is currently executing

**CurrentViewController.m**

```
-(void)methodExecutingOnCurrentViewController
{
    //some code..

    // what method do I call in order to load and move to my FirstViewController at this point?

    // do I first initialize an instance of the ViewController I want to move to?
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];


    // but now how do I actually move to this instance I've just created? 
    // I couldn't find the appropriate method in the class reference documentation

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`[Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are many other ways you could accomplish what you are looking for, are you using a navigation controller? Then `- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` is what you want. You could also just add that controller's view as a subview to your current viewController.

Comment: I'm not using a Navigation Controller (I'll have to look into that..) but will `presentViewController:animated:completion:` do the job for now anyway or are there any risks? Thanks!

Comment: You should be fine. Just remember that you need to know when that new viewController needs dismissing so you can call `- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`. Per doc "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."

Comment: You should give the documentation a good look or you'll run into problems if you want to do something more complex. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to all three of you. Much Appreciated!

Comment: @ohr is correct! but please be aware that presenting a view controller modally almost always means that no other view controller will be presented from that view controller. always take this into account when presenting modal view controllers. and setting up a navigation controller is really not hard at all :P

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a UINavigationController (and if you are not, you should) you can do like this:

```
[self.navigationController.pushViewController pushViewController: firstViewController animated:YES];
```

This pushes a view controller onto the navigation stack.

You can also present view controllers modally. You should read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html) and decide what's best for you.

Comment: It's one of those annoying things that happen when you are a newbie, where your project has gotten too big and you never thought about using a NavigationController and now I'm just too scared to introduce that to my project and mess with all the necessary changes :)

Comment: it's really not that hard! all you need to do to get a (fairly basic) navigation stack, is in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` instead of setting your view controller as the root view controller, create a navigation controller using `UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewControllerHere]` and set that as the root view controller. then you are good to go!

Comment: How can I have global access to that navigation Controller I've created? I mean every time I am in some xViewController and I need to move to some yViewController I guess I need to pop that xViewController and push that yViewController onto my stack by calling my navigationController.. Where do I create it and how can I access it from any ViewController is what's confusing me..

Comment: you create it in the app delegate. like I said, instead of making whatever view controller you are making as the root view controller of your `window` object in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the app delegate, you create a navigation controller like i specified. you can call it from whatever view controller by simply calling `self.navigationController`!

Answer (score 1):

base your project in a navigation controller and simply do push

> SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
>
> ```
>      [self.navigationController secondVC animated:YES];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use UINavigationController, you can move to other UIViewcontroller by this way:

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:^{}];}];
```